# Why Scroll bar appear in browser when we use bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When we use bootstrap then we use "row" for full width and inside it we use container for some width in any screen,but scroll is appear in our site,but we use all the bootstrap classes and width but also scroll bar appear-why?

please give me some suggestion

Comment: Your question should include some code of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying, I presume that you have improper nesting of various divs.

The answer can be found in bootstrap's documentation.

You can not nest Containers div.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

> Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.

Addtionally, rows can not be put outside a container but only inside.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

So you must always start with a container div before adding row divs.

Then close containers, before starting new ones (if you need to do that).